# Create a list using php

Tags: php, for-loop

Hey everyone i need to create a list using php.But i wanna print the odd number in left position and the even number in right position.
Some help please, thanks

my code

```
<?php
$min = 100;
$max = 110;
?>
<ul class="wrap-list">
<?php
for($i=$min;$i<= $max,$i++) {
    echo "<li>$min</li>";
}
?>
</ul>
```

Comment: This sounds like a homework question ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply do:

```
<?php
$min = 100;
$max = 110;
?>
<ul class="wrap-list">
<?php
for($i=$min;$i<=$max,$i+=2) {
    echo "<li>$min | ".($min+1)."</li>";
}
?>
</ul>
```

Or if you're looking for something a bit cleaner, you could output it as:

```
<?php
$min = 100;
$max = 110;
?>
<table class="wrap-list">
<?php
for($i=$min;$i<=$max,$i+=2) {
    echo "<tr><td>$min</td><td>".($min+1)."</td></tr>";
}
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Just one nit from me. You're using double quotes, so variable sub is going to be run, so you're using a variable sub on the left, and a string concat on the right when you don't need to.

Comment: Just do the math outside the echo, or don't use double quotes. Not a performance issue given the small size of the set, but readability wise it matters somewhat